# Fastest way to read data from a lot of ASCII files

Tags: c++, io, buffer, ifstream

for a college exercise that I've already submitted I needed to read a .txt file wich contained a lot of names of images(1 in each line). 
Then I needed to open each image as an ascii file, and read their data(images where in ppm format), and do a series of things with them.
The things is, I noticed my program was taking 70% of the time in the reading the data from the file part, instead of in the other calculations that I was doing (finding number of repetitions of each pixel with a hash table, finding diferents pixels beetween 2 images etc..), which I found quite odd to say the least.

This is how the ppm format looks like:

```
P3 //This value can be ignored when reading the file, because all image will be correctly formatted
4 4
255 //This value can be also ignored, will be always 255.
0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0   15  0 15
0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0    0  0  0
0  0  0    0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0
15  0 15    0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0
```

This is how I was reading the data from the files:

```
ifstream fdatos;
fdatos.open(argv[1]); //Open file with the name of all the images

const int size = 128;
char file[size]; //Where I'll get the image name

Image *img;
while (fdatos >> file) { //While there's still images anmes left, continue
    ifstream fimagen;
fimagen.open(file);  //Open image file
img = new Image(fimagen); //Create new image object with it's data file
    ………
    //Rest of the calculations whith that image
    ………
delete img; //Delete image object after done 
    fimagen.close(); //Close image file after done
}

fdatos.close();
```

And inside the image object read the data like this:

```
const int tallafirma = 100;
char firma[tallafirma];
fich_in >> std::setw(100) >> firma; // Read the P3 part, can be ignored

int maxvalue, numpixels;
fich_in >> height >> width >> maxvalue; // Read the next three values
numpixels = height*width;
datos = new Pixel[numpixels];

int r,g,b; //Don't need to be ints, max value is 256, so an unsigned char would be ok.
for (int i=0; i<numpixels; i++) {
   fich_in >> r >> g >> b;
   datos[i] = Pixel( r, g ,b);
}
//This last part is the slow one, 
//I thing I should be able to read all this data in one single read 
//to buffer or something which would be stored in an array of unsigned chars, 
//and  then I'd only need to to do:
//buffer[0] -> //Pixel 1 - Red data
//buffer[1] -> //Pixel 1 - Green data
//buffer[2] -> //Pixel 1 - Blue data
```

So, any Ideas? I think I can improve it quite a bit reading all to an array in one single call, I just don't know how that is done.

Also, is it posible to know how many images will be in the "index file"? Is it posiible to know the number of lines a file has?(because there's one file name per line..)

Thanks!!

EDIT: This is How I emasure the time.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
double get_time()
{
  struct timeval t;
  struct timezone tzp;
  gettimeofday(&t, &tzp);
  return t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec*1e-6;
}

double start = get_time();
//Everything to be measured here.
double end = get_time();

cout << end-start << endl;
```

Comment: Well, I am one of the lectures of this subject and the organizer of the programming contest that this student is participating. Feel free to help him, but it is suppose that the students have to solve the contest by their own, or just reading different programming sources but not using an active query to the community.

Anyway as i have detected this queries, any other participant can, and the copy is completely forbidden........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating memory and deleting it in each loop. I don't think that is good if you so concern about performance.

So one improvement you can do is: **reuse the memory once it is allocated to your program**.

```
void *memory = malloc(sizeof(Image)); //reusable memory. 

//placement new to construct the object in the already allocated memory!
img = new (memory) Image(fimagen);

//...

img->~Image(); //calling the destructor

//when you're done free the memory
free(memory); //use free, as we had used malloc when allocating!
```

Likewise, you can reuse memory in the `Image` class, especially at this line:

```
 datos = new Pixel[numpixels];
```

---

And finally, instead of reading RGB into local variables, then copying them into the image data, is not that elegant, so a little improvement can be done here as well,

```
 //this is yours : temporaries, and copying!
 fich_in >> r >> g >> b;
 datos[i] = Pixel( r, g ,b);

 //this is mine : no temporaries, no copying. directly reading into image data!
 fich_in >> datos[i].r >> datos[i].g >> datos[i].b;
```

Besides these, I don't think there is much scope to improve your code performance wise!

Comment: Well,I didn't know I could actually do that, I'm quite new in all of this.I'll try and see if it helps something. Also, I'm not so concern, It's just that I noticed that and saw that people read whole files to a buffer and I though that would improve things because you only ened to access one time to the disk??.I don't know.

Comment: Well, @Nawaz, that was it! the temporaries and the copying on the RGB variables. Testing it with a small set (30 256x256 images) makes the time go down from 0.23 to 0.098. Holy smokes xD

Comment: @Nawaz, one last thing, does that void pointer to memory needs to be manually deallocate? Because I've pute a delete memory at the end but I get errors compiling it.

Comment: @Alsenes: You cannot use `delete` to deallocate memory which was allocated using `malloc`. Anyway, I added this part to answer. Check it out. :-)

Comment: No surprise in the improvement you got.  But I believe if you read the file in large chunks into a buffer you'll get a much faster solution than you do now!  You see, when you read just a small amount and the disk continues spinning, you'll need to wait for the spin to be in place again for the next read.  Since files (especially if not so large) are written in continuous chinks on the disk, reading them in one go saves you a LOT of time.

You should at least read a line each time, and then read from the buffer of that line (that you should reuse as Nawaz showed you).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to compute the number of lines in a textfile without reading the entire file.

As for other optimizations, use the `time` command (if you're on Unix/Linux) to check if the program uses a lot of "user" time (actual computation) compared to its "wallclock" time (total time between start and end of process). If not, you're probably waiting for the disk or network.

Comment: What does this method do? Get clock time, compute, get clock time, report difference?

Comment: sorry I was editing, I've update the wuestion with the method I use.

Comment: Ok. Well, that measures only the wallclock time (the time elapsed during execution). Use the `time` command (`time ./myprogram`) to get the user and system time, which are much more interesting.

Comment: Hey! nice command, thanks. With a small set of images , before I was getting with my measure Time : 0.22142. Your time command gives me, real 0m0.228, user 0m0.214 and sys 0m0.010. How do I interpret that? Also, If I remove all the calculations and only left the data read parts, it takes 0.18728.

Comment: @Alsenes: it means my hunch was wrong; I've updated the post. The program spends most of its time in "user mode", i.e. doing its own computations. `sys` is the time spent in the kernel, handling your I/O requests. The "missing" time (`real` - `user` - `sys`) is time spent waiting for the disk to spin.