# Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input:Error termination. Backtrace:

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is .dat file 2000 x 2000, and I am trying to read .dat file in fortran, I am beginner in fortran and tried all different ways to read the file.  and when I run the file, it gives me Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input error. If anyone can explain to me, what's going one here?

I also checked, the file which I want to read is in current directory.

I have  to print this .dat file, in compiler.
Is there any minor error in my code?
Here is the data first three rows, its image data

1.1300000e+02      1.1300000e+02       1.1300000e+02       1.1300000e+02       1.1300000e+02       1.1300000e+02       1.1500000e+02       1.1500000e+02       1.1500000e+02       1.1500000e+02       1.1500000e+02       1.1500000e+02       1.1600000e+02       1.1600000e+02       1.1600000e+02       1.1600000e+02       1.1600000e+02      1.1600000e+02

Here are two different ways, I tried to get a data,(there are more ways I tried, but didn't work, show I tried showing what I try latest)

```
           program testpro
             implicit none
             !reads data from a file called mydata.dat
              real :: i,j
            open(unit=10,file='mydata.dat')
            read(10,*) i,j
            print *,i,j
            end program  testpro




         program Test2

         REAL :: mx,my,mz
         doubleprecision, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: B
         integer :: i, j, k
         
         read (*,*) mx,my,mz             
         open(10,file='mydata.dat',status='old')

         read (10,*) mx,my,mz
         allocate (B(mx,my,mz) )

         read(10,*)(((B(i,j,k),i=1,mx),j=1,my),k=1,mz)
         close(10)
         end program Test2
```

Comment: What are the first 30 characters of the file?  Is a binary file or ascii?  Does the file `mydata.dat` actually exist?

Comment: ascii format, and few lines from data looks like this 3.9200000e+04    3.9700000e+04    1.2400000e+04    6.6400000e+04

Comment: I tried using this code too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082794/ascii-data-import-how-can-i-match-fortrans-bulk-read-performance-in-c), and gives kind of same error as this code. Error: Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input.

Comment: Do not use comments for important information. Please [edit] your question and use proper formatting. Show the exact form of the text file. Double or triple check that the file is really located where it should be. If not, your program will create an empty file instead.

Comment: `1.1300000e+02` doesn't make an integer, and yet an integer is what you are asking to read.

Comment: Then can you help, how am I suppose to read?

Comment: `read (10,*) mx,my,mz` is asking to read a head with the shape of the array to be read. You need to provide this header in the file, or remove that reading.#

Comment: I also checked, the file, which I want to read is in current directory. But then I need to remove allocate as well and if I comment out both of them, then it doesn't return anything,  Can you explain bit more, or I understood wrong?

Comment: Well, you need to add an initial line to the data file with 3 integer values for `mx, my, mz`.  Or, you can read those from standard input with `read(*,*) mx, my, mz`.

Comment: but even if I make these changes, all I get is Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input, does it have to do something with input file, I opened it many times and it looks good

Answer (score 0):

Your file contains `imax*jmax` values (`imax` lines and `jmax` row). So at each lines you have to read `j` values from `1` to `jmax` and repeat this for the `i` lines from `1` to `imax`. To do a such thing you need to manage your data in an array. I suggest to create a variable `x` with dimension `(imax,jmax)` and use a nested loop to read. For example

```
PROGRAM TEST_read_from_file
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER          :: i, j
integer, parameter :: imax=10,jmax=5
REAL :: x(imax,jmax)

! create the test.dat file
Open (unit=1,file='./test.dat',status='unknown')
  do i=1,imax
    write (1,*) (rand(0),j=1,jmax)
  enddo
close(1)
! read the file test.dat
Open (unit=2,file='./test.dat',status='old')
  do i=1,imax
    read (2,*) (x(i,j),j=1,jmax)
  enddo
close(2)
! write x on the terminal
do i=1,imax
  write(*,*) (x(i,j),j=1,jmax)
enddo
END PROGRAM TEST_read_from_file
```

Note that 2000x2000 array might be too big (4°000°000 values)

Comment: are you sure, I thing your program name has to be same. Isn't it has to be program test and End program test. Thanks for help, your help , does give me some output, but I want to know why you are doing create file, isn't all we do here is read and write?

Comment: @Beginner_Learner Yes, sure. I correct the programm name right now. I don't have the file you are aiming to read, so I write something in order to have a the file in my folder

Comment: It gave me same error, Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input. Can you explain some more, about the error I am getting.

Comment: Your file contains values such as 1.1300000e+02 that are real kind not integer. While you are trying to put those real in a variable that is declared as integer. So you have a mismatch between what the file contains and the variable where you try to put your variable. In the example I gave, if you declare x as an integer you will have same error message, namelly "Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input"

Comment: You know what your file contains. It is 2000x2000 values that are real. As you are reading the file, you consider that you are reading an integer. When you open the file your first cmd is read mx,my and mz. These variales are declared as integer. So here you have a mismatch. Also you have to close the file somewhere.

Comment: thanks for debugging, I clear that out as well

Comment: it still give me error, I think format is missing, but I am not sure, which way to go.and still gives me Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input